# Gravar Radio Button Mysql PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho um sistema em PHP, JavaScript e MYSQL onde a pessoa monta seu pedido...

[Link para o site](http://placasparatumulo.com.br/foto-porcelana-01#.)

Está funcionando corretamente, mas preciso passar dados para um relatório e não sei como fazer...

Ex. Tamanho 06x08 - Oval - Sem Moldura...

No input radio de cada item o value está setado com o valor de cada peça.

Assim não consigo passar via POST ou GET qual é a escolha do cliente...

Ele me passa apenas os valores

Ex. de um input radio

```
<input type="radio" value="10.00" name="moldura" id="btn_medida02_oval_sm">
```

Comment: O único valor passado via POST/GET é o atributo `value` associado ao `name` do campo. Qual outro valor você esperaria passar?

Comment: Quero o passar o nome do item selecionado... Ex: Tamanho 06x08cm. O valor atribuido a ele no value vem do banco de dados

Comment: Tem como eu passar o preco, sem usar o value do radio button?

Comment: Quais são as informações que você precisa enviar, de fato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tem como eu passar o preco, sem usar o value do radio button?

Crie um input to tipo hidden, ou vários se ficar mais fácil de entender.

```
<input type="hidden" name="campo_oculto" value="">
```

E no evento click você adiciona os valores no input hidden.

Onde você quer colocar o evento click você acrescenta um id, embaixo da tag que você importou o jquery adicione o seguinte código:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_onde_vc_clica').click(function(){
        $('#id_do_campo_hidden').val($('#id_onde_esta_o_valor').val());
    });
});
```

Se o valor estiver desta forma, dentro do atributo value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="campo_oculto" id="teste" value="informacao aqui">
```

Você utiliza o val para pegar o valor

```
$('#teste').val();
```

Mas se o valor esta desta forma:

```
<span id="teste">informacao aqui</span>
```

Você utiliza text, para pegar o valor:

```
$('#teste').text();
```

Comment: como eu adicionaria isso no click? nao consegui

Comment: Fiz uma edição com um pequeno exemplo.

Comment: Legal... Fiz aqui os testes e foi... mas como mandar apenas os q eu selecionei.... Tamanho 1 - Formato 1 - Moldura 2... Neste caso esta indo todos os formatos (1 e 2) e todas as Molduras (1 e 2). Nao apenas as q eu selecionei

Comment: Assim ele retorna se ele esta chegado ou não $("#id_do_radio").is(':checked')